# Apache Httpd mod_jk uses only one worker

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I have a problem with mod_jk works only with one tomcat worker and I don't have a clue what is wrong...
I have two Tomcats with almost the same config except of working port, shutdown port and ajp port (in one of them i have changed it to 8008). Now when I go to main url always fist worker responds even when i turn it down second worker is not used and request to application fails.
Please help, I can't figure it out since tomorrow.

Here is my wokrers.properties:

```
#Worker for load balancing

worker.list=loadbal

worker.loadbal.type=lb
worker.loadbal.balance_workers=worker1,worker2
worker.loadbal.method=R

#worker.loadbal.sticky_session=1
#worker.stat1.type=status

worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.redirect=worker2
worker.worker1.type=ajp13


worker.worker2.port=8008
worker.worker2.host=localhost
worker.worker2.redirect=worker1
worker.worker2.type=ajp13
```

Here is my apache2.conf(what I added)

```
ServerName localhost

LoadModule    jk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so
LoadModule    jk_module mod_jk.c
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile     /etc/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    debug
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
```

And a debug output when apache2 is being started:

```
[Mon May 22 13:32:18 2017] [7691:140171105404736] [debug] jk_shm_close::jk_shm.c (700): Closed shared memory /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7685 childs=3
[Mon May 22 13:32:18 2017] [7692:140171105404736] [debug] jk_shm_close::jk_shm.c (700): Closed shared memory /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7685 childs=2
[Mon May 22 13:32:18 2017] [7685:140171105404736] [debug] jk_shm_close::jk_shm.c (700): Closed shared memory /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7685 childs=1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_set_time_fmt::jk_util.c (461): Pre-processed log time stamp format is '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] '
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_open::jk_uri_worker_map.c (861): rule map size is 0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (176): uri map dump after map open: id=0, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 collapse_slashes=3 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_set_time_fmt::jk_util.c (461): Pre-processed log time stamp format is '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] '
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3305): Using fcntl() for locking.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3321): Setting default connection pool max size to 25
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.list' with value 'loadbal' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.loadbal.type' with value 'lb' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.loadbal.balance_workers' with value 'worker1,worker2' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.loadbal.method' with value 'R' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker1.port' with value '8009' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker1.host' with value 'localhost' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker1.redirect' with value 'worker2' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker1.type' with value 'ajp13' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker2.port' with value '8008' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker2.host' with value 'localhost' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker2.redirect' with value 'worker1' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker2.type' with value 'ajp13' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_resolve_references::jk_map.c (764): Checking for references with prefix worker. with wildcard (recursion 1)
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_shm_calculate_size::jk_shm.c (129): worker loadbal of type lb has 2 members
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_shm_calculate_size::jk_shm.c (136): shared memory will contain 0 ajp workers and 1 lb workers with 2 members
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (579): Truncated shared memory to 2560
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (624): Initialized shared memory /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7814 size=2560 free=1920 addr=0x7f5a933e9000
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (489): Opened shared memory lock /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7814.lock
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'ServerRoot' -> '/etc/apache2'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.list' -> 'loadbal'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.loadbal.type' -> 'lb'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.loadbal.balance_workers' -> 'worker1,worker2'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.loadbal.method' -> 'R'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker1.port' -> '8009'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker1.host' -> 'localhost'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker1.redirect' -> 'worker2'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker1.type' -> 'ajp13'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker2.port' -> '8008'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker2.host' -> 'localhost'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker2.redirect' -> 'worker1'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker2.type' -> 'ajp13'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] build_worker_map::jk_worker.c (241): creating worker loadbal
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance loadbal of lb
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init loadbal
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance worker1 of ajp13
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_worker_factory::jk_ajp_common.c (3023): ajp worker 'worker1' type=2 created
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init worker1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2691): worker worker1 contact is 'localhost:8009'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_ajp_push::jk_ajp_common.c (1113): syncing shm for ajp worker 'worker1' from mem (0->0) [0->0]
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2887): setting endpoint options:
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2890): keepalive:              0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2894): socket timeout:         0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2898): socket connect timeout: 0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2902): buffer size:            0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2906): pool timeout:           0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2910): ping timeout:           10000
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2914): connect timeout:        0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2918): reply timeout:          0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2922): prepost timeout:        0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2926): recovery options:       0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2930): retries:                2
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2934): max packet size:        8192
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2938): retry interval:         100
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_create_endpoint_cache::jk_ajp_common.c (2750): setting connection pool size to 25 with min 13 and acquire timeout 200
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance worker2 of ajp13
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_worker_factory::jk_ajp_common.c (3023): ajp worker 'worker2' type=2 created
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init worker2
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2691): worker worker2 contact is 'localhost:8008'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_ajp_push::jk_ajp_common.c (1113): syncing shm for ajp worker 'worker2' from mem (0->0) [0->0]
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2887): setting endpoint options:
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2890): keepalive:              0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2894): socket timeout:         0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2898): socket connect timeout: 0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2902): buffer size:            0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2906): pool timeout:           0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2910): ping timeout:           10000
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2914): connect timeout:        0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2918): reply timeout:          0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2922): prepost timeout:        0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2926): recovery options:       0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2930): retries:                2
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2934): max packet size:        8192
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2938): retry interval:         100
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_create_endpoint_cache::jk_ajp_common.c (2750): setting connection pool size to 25 with min 13 and acquire timeout 200
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] validate::jk_lb_worker.c (1725): Balanced worker 0 has name worker1 and route worker1 in domain 
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] validate::jk_lb_worker.c (1725): Balanced worker 1 has name worker2 and route worker2 in domain 
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] update_mult::jk_lb_worker.c (262): worker worker1 gets multiplicity 1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] update_mult::jk_lb_worker.c (262): worker worker2 gets multiplicity 1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_lb_push::jk_lb_worker.c (358): syncing shm for lb 'loadbal' from mem (0->0)
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3383): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (176): uri map dump after extension stripping: id=1, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 collapse_slashes=16384 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_switch::jk_uri_worker_map.c (588): Switching uri worker map from index 0 to index 1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7814:140026995992384] [debug] jk_shm_close::jk_shm.c (700): Closed shared memory /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7814 childs=1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_set_time_fmt::jk_util.c (461): Pre-processed log time stamp format is '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] '
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_open::jk_uri_worker_map.c (861): rule map size is 0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (176): uri map dump after map open: id=0, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 collapse_slashes=3 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_set_time_fmt::jk_util.c (461): Pre-processed log time stamp format is '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] '
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3305): Using fcntl() for locking.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3321): Setting default connection pool max size to 25
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.list' with value 'loadbal' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.loadbal.type' with value 'lb' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.loadbal.balance_workers' with value 'worker1,worker2' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.loadbal.method' with value 'R' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker1.port' with value '8009' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker1.host' with value 'localhost' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker1.redirect' with value 'worker2' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker1.type' with value 'ajp13' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker2.port' with value '8008' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker2.host' with value 'localhost' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker2.redirect' with value 'worker1' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_read_property::jk_map.c (482): Adding property 'worker.worker2.type' with value 'ajp13' to map.
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_resolve_references::jk_map.c (764): Checking for references with prefix worker. with wildcard (recursion 1)
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_shm_calculate_size::jk_shm.c (129): worker loadbal of type lb has 2 members
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_shm_calculate_size::jk_shm.c (136): shared memory will contain 0 ajp workers and 1 lb workers with 2 members
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (579): Truncated shared memory to 2560
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (624): Initialized shared memory /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7815 size=2560 free=1920 addr=0x7f5a935b4000
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (489): Opened shared memory lock /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7815.lock
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'ServerRoot' -> '/etc/apache2'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.list' -> 'loadbal'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.loadbal.type' -> 'lb'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.loadbal.balance_workers' -> 'worker1,worker2'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.loadbal.method' -> 'R'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker1.port' -> '8009'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker1.host' -> 'localhost'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker1.redirect' -> 'worker2'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker1.type' -> 'ajp13'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker2.port' -> '8008'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker2.host' -> 'localhost'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker2.redirect' -> 'worker1'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_map_dump::jk_map.c (580): Dump of map 2: 'worker.worker2.type' -> 'ajp13'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] build_worker_map::jk_worker.c (241): creating worker loadbal
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance loadbal of lb
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init loadbal
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance worker1 of ajp13
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_worker_factory::jk_ajp_common.c (3023): ajp worker 'worker1' type=2 created
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init worker1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2691): worker worker1 contact is 'localhost:8009'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_ajp_push::jk_ajp_common.c (1113): syncing shm for ajp worker 'worker1' from mem (0->0) [0->0]
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2887): setting endpoint options:
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2890): keepalive:              0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2894): socket timeout:         0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2898): socket connect timeout: 0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2902): buffer size:            0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2906): pool timeout:           0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2910): ping timeout:           10000
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2914): connect timeout:        0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2918): reply timeout:          0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2922): prepost timeout:        0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2926): recovery options:       0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2930): retries:                2
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2934): max packet size:        8192
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2938): retry interval:         100
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_create_endpoint_cache::jk_ajp_common.c (2750): setting connection pool size to 25 with min 13 and acquire timeout 200
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (145): about to create instance worker2 of ajp13
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_worker_factory::jk_ajp_common.c (3023): ajp worker 'worker2' type=2 created
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] wc_create_worker::jk_worker.c (158): about to validate and init worker2
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_validate::jk_ajp_common.c (2691): worker worker2 contact is 'localhost:8008'
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_ajp_push::jk_ajp_common.c (1113): syncing shm for ajp worker 'worker2' from mem (0->0) [0->0]
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2887): setting endpoint options:
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2890): keepalive:              0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2894): socket timeout:         0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2898): socket connect timeout: 0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2902): buffer size:            0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2906): pool timeout:           0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2910): ping timeout:           10000
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2914): connect timeout:        0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2918): reply timeout:          0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2922): prepost timeout:        0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2926): recovery options:       0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2930): retries:                2
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2934): max packet size:        8192
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_init::jk_ajp_common.c (2938): retry interval:         100
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] ajp_create_endpoint_cache::jk_ajp_common.c (2750): setting connection pool size to 25 with min 13 and acquire timeout 200
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] validate::jk_lb_worker.c (1725): Balanced worker 0 has name worker1 and route worker1 in domain 
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] validate::jk_lb_worker.c (1725): Balanced worker 1 has name worker2 and route worker2 in domain 
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] update_mult::jk_lb_worker.c (262): worker worker1 gets multiplicity 1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] update_mult::jk_lb_worker.c (262): worker worker2 gets multiplicity 1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] jk_lb_push::jk_lb_worker.c (358): syncing shm for lb 'loadbal' from mem (0->0)
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3383): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (176): uri map dump after extension stripping: id=1, index=0 file='(null)' reject_unsafe=0 collapse_slashes=16384 reload=60 modified=0 checked=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 0: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_dump::jk_uri_worker_map.c (183): generation 1: size=0 nosize=0 capacity=0
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7815:140026995992384] [debug] uri_worker_map_switch::jk_uri_worker_map.c (588): Switching uri worker map from index 0 to index 1
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7824:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (634): Attached shared memory /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7815 [2] size=2560 workers=4 free=0 addr=0x7f5a935b4000
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7824:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (430): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7815.lock
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7824:140026995992384] [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3266): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.37
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7822:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open::jk_shm.c (634): Attached shared memory /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7815 [3] size=2560 workers=4 free=0 addr=0x7f5a935b4000
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7822:140026995992384] [debug] do_shm_open_lock::jk_shm.c (430): Duplicated shared memory lock /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status.7815.lock
[Mon May 22 13:32:19 2017] [7822:140026995992384] [debug] jk_child_init::mod_jk.c (3266): Initialized mod_jk/1.2.37
```

Comment: Please show your mapping rules in the httpd.conf for the incoming requests.

Comment: Can you clarify: are you saying when you take `worker1` out of service, `worker2` is not used? Can you post a log of what happens when `worker1` is removed from service and you try to send a request? Your log only shows a standard startup.

Comment: I figured it out...
I've had a hardcoded proxy settings in sites-enabled/000-default file like:

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

I have changed it to: 

    JkMount /* loadbal

and it works like a charm ;)